# migrating computation to the cloud

Tags: java, refactoring, hadoop, cloud, mapreduce

Is there any automatic tool that I can transform legacy uniprocessor programs to the cloud, meaning that the target program is ready to execute in the cloud (e.g. programs written for Hadoop)? If not, what are the best practices when doing such transformations (maybe total rewrite) manually? Also, how can I know/evaluate whether a legacy program (or programming task) is suitable for computing?

Example: suppose I have a WordCount program written solely with standard Java library (e.g. HashMap), how can I transform it to one written with Hadoop like the one provided in the sample code of the Hadoop distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any automatic tool that I can transform legacy uniprocessor programs to the cloud?

I don't think there is an automatic tool that can transform a legacy uniprocessor program to the cloud.

If the legacy program is written using the MapReduce paradigm then it should be somewhat easy to run in a cloud using Hadoop with some modifications. If not then the problem has to be thought in a MapReduce way and rewritten for Hadoop using Java or some other language which supports read/write to the STDIN/STDOUT.

Also, if the language in which the legacy program was written can read/write to the STDIN/STDOUT then you can use [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/streaming.html).

> Also, how can I know/evaluate whether a legacy program (or programming task) is suitable for computing?

If the processing can happen in parallel **independently** and the data can also be split across more than one machine, then it might be a suitable candidate for Hadoop.

HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System) is designed for high latency and high throughput. If, the requirement is for low latency then you might consider HBase.

Also, HDFS is designed for large file (GB, TB and PB). If the legacy application has too many small file then an [alternative approach](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/) has to be considered.

> Some more things to consider.

Hadoop runs straight out of the box with some minimum configuration changes, but to run it efficiently a lot of parameters have to be tweaked and some times it's required to get straight into the code.

Also, try to a POC and start with something small to solve the problem area and evaluate the pros and cons.

Suggest to buy ['Hadoop : The Definitive Guide'](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do) book.

Answer (score 0):

Like any concurrent application, it has to be able to do multiple independant things at the same time.  If you want this to be faster you have save time more than the overhead distributing the application takes.

In the example of the word count, your bottleneck is like to be how fast it can read the file from disk.  To distribute the word count efficiently you have to have copies of the file (or portions of the file) on each machine.  This of course can take much longer than it saves.

However say file access is not your bottleneck, you can break the file(s) into portions so that each thread or node can count the words in that portion and then sum the results to get the total.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of folks looking for magic tools to convert programs implemented using serial computing methods, into ones that are highly parallel.

Mostly this doesn't work, as the parallelism isn't easily found in the code either a) because it isn't there, or b) because the analysis required to see it is beyond the present technology of the tools.

If the parallelism can be found by a tool, or simply marked as present by a programmer ("annotations", "directives", see OpenMP) for example, there are tools that can automatically insert parallelism directives.

These tools are mostly found in the Fortran space (to suppport supercomputing tasks).    There are some research tools for Java; lots of Universities doing "Java" + "Parallelism" because it a hot topic in a "cool" [meaning "available"] langauge.   I doubt you'll find a tool that really works for a University for this; they only do demos.

I'd guess you're stuck, and you'll have to do this yourself.